# Chemical bond-covalent-valence electrons OH-

Tags: bond, electrons, covalent-compounds

I would like to ask how many valence electrons took part in creating chemical bond in $\ce{OH-}$? Is the minus related to $\ce{O}$ or to $\ce{H}$? Are there any spare valence electrons which didnt take part in creating chemical bond in $\ce{OH-}$?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the photo the orange electrons are non bond electrons.
And the black electrons are bond electrons.

There are 2 electrons took part in creating chemical bond in $\ce{OH}$.
The first one is from oxygen.
The second is from hydrogen.

This kind of bond is called "Covalent bond".
For more about Covalent bond : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond

The minus is  related to  the black and white electrons that are free (in Oxygen).

The white electron is come from other element.